# Кастомный onReceivedError()

Tags: android, webview

Мне и пользователям не нравится стандартный экран в `WebView` при отсутствии интернета.

Что если при вызове этого метода сохранять загруженный адрес, затем запускать намерение для перехода в активность, отображающую нужную информацию с кнопкой "Обновить"? При её нажатии произойдёт обратный переход в игру и загрузится сохраненный не загруженный адрес.

Вот метод **onReceivedError():**

```
wv.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient()
    {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String url, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            url = LASTNO;
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoActivity.class));

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
```

В методе **onCreate():**

```
if (LASTNO != null) wv.loadUrl(LASTNO);
```

Активность, Xml, манифест - все готово, все правильно. Но никаких изменений не заметно. Все тот же " ВЕБ СТРАНИЦА НЕДОСТУПНА...

Comment: `onReceivedError` вызывается уже после того, как веб-страница отрендерилась, так что в любом случае, даже если вы запустите новую Activity, на долю секунды будет отображаться *Веб страница недоступна*. В вашем случае вы можете попробовать сделать обработку отсутствия сети при помощи `BroadcastReceiver`, например как тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/3767766/1568530

Comment: @metalurgus, спасибо, уже сам справился) У меня схема интересная получилась) тот экран больше не показывается. Только мой. Протестил на 2.3.6 .. а как можно убрать анимацию перехода между активностями? Мне не нужна она вообще.

Comment: 1. Раз вы нашли решение, ответьте на свой вопрос, и выложите решение. 2. Если у вас возник другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Comment: metalurgus, 1) больно много кода, и объяснений в именно моём случае, что выдаст мою идею

Comment: @metalurgus, 2) сейчас